# android login form

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have developed a login form for my app. The app works successfully.

This is **my current o/p** :

The problem is If I have to enter the correct login information means its displayed **success** message after that go to next activity.

If i have to enter the wrong information means just displayed login failed message and redirect to same login page.

**Wish to need the o/p** like:

If I have to enter the correct login details means its directly go to next activity and shouldn't display success message.

But if I have to  enter the wrong login details means **login fail** message should be displayed.

In this app.,

I have used below code in WebService:

```
  if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)&&!(retrievedUserName.equals("") && retrievedPassword.equals(""))){
   status = "Success";
```

also wrote the below condition on android side:

```
  if(status.equals("Success"))
```

Now if I have to enter my login username and password correctly, it will display **Success** message and go to next activity. If login is failed, **login failed** message is displayed here successfully.

But same time I have to write the code on webservice side:

```
if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)&&!(retrievedUserName.equals("") && retrievedPassword.equals(""))){
   status = "";
```

also wrote the android side means

```
if(status.equals(""))
```

Now when I enter my login username and password correctly, it shouldn't display success message also nothing is happened.
But If I enter the wrong login details, *login failed* message is displayed properly.

Comment: Make your question goals briefer and cleaner

Comment: have you tried displaying **success** message. If it is displaying the success message, then there is definitely something wrong with the intent you are creating to start next activity. and please dont make a mess of your code, just post the relavent matter, avoid using import and other irrelavent statements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming retrievedUserName and retrievedPassword are fetched from database, change the web service as below.

```
if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)){
   status = "Success"; //login success
} else {
   status = "";  //login failed
}
```

Coming to calling web service from UI, use AsyncTask class as below. Try not to use network calls in the main UI thread.

```
class BgRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
      //perform login authentication
      //call webservice method
      return <result of authentication>
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String loginStatus) {
        if(null != loginStatus && loginStatus.equals("Success")) {
            //start new activity                
        } else {
           //login failed
           //print login failed message on UI
        }
    }
}
```

Read [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details.

a small piece of advice. Keep the question simple and concise! You receive prompt responses that way.

By the way, I reckon this answer will keep you going.

Comment: let me clearly get into this. So if login is authenticated, the web service returns "success" and "" otherwise..?

Comment: if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password) returns true, there is no need for further checks. But if the web service is properly returning login status message, clear all ui implementations from web service and create AsyncTask instead. It works!